# Adobe Air AS3 show Notifiacation to user

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, toast

How to show a message to the user, exactly like the the text "Uninstall Finished" in the image in URL

visit : http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/nexusae0_2013-01-23-23.02.44_thumb.png

while the app is open.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What you see on your posted image is called a `Toast` in android, as far as i know, and Adobe AIR has no built-in capabilities to deal with that. But you should be able to write a simple Native Extension for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Air does not support native OS functionality (for both iOS and Android).

The only way to achieve messaging to the user would be through the use of push notifications or some in-app message.

Adobe Native Extensions (ANEs) will be your best bet.

Do note that iOS and Android deal with push notifications differently and it is not a completely trivial process.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to, will be necessary to use a Native Extension, it's not hard, and there is a lot of tutorials, examples, free and paid Native Extensions.

You can read more about how to create a Native Extension [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html)
Find a lot of Native Extensions [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)

I have tried some free Native Extensions and recommend you to give a try to [this one](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification), they have Push and Local notifications.
Hope will be possible to help, somehow.